# Sending multiple images to chromecast via IOS results in flickering

Tags: ios, stream, chromecast

I want to send an image stream to a chromecast from iOS using the API and not a custom receiver.

I can send images on a NSTimer using this code

```
GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation =
[[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:url
                                    streamType:GCKMediaStreamTypeNone
                                   contentType:@"image/jpg"
                                      metadata:nil
                                streamDuration:0
                                    customData:nil];

//cast video
[_mediaControlChannel loadMedia:mediaInformation autoplay:TRUE playPosition:0];
```

but there is heavy flickering between each frame. Is the API capable of seamless image transfer?

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to APIs; this is a matter of how you handle multiple images and transitions between them on the receiver side; the Default/Styled receiver do not do anything special for that sort of things; you need to write your own receiver.

Comment: I am using the API, i am getting a flicker. I think thats clear.

Comment: APIs are responsible for getting urls to the receiver, presentation of images is up to the receiver, so whether you think it is clear or not, it is not a matter of APIs.

Comment: so the API isnt capable of sending a new image url without blanking the screen for a second. that would be a huge advantage to the many applications that need this that have authentification, and clientside JS is not secure or practical.

Comment: It seems I can't get my message across. The presentation of what you see on the TV screen is done by the receiver application; there is no single sender api that cares about the presentation on TV; if you want a different way of presenting images or transitioning between images, you need to write your own receiver.

Comment: i understand you perfectly. there is a default receiver that should support what i want to do, but doesnt. https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps

Comment: You need to write your own receiver; the Default receiver is not designed for that.